# FragmentActivity and LocationListener

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, locationlistener

I try to get the current Location of the User using LocationListener in a FragmentActivity (in order to user SupportMapFragment) that implements LocationListener.

This is my code :

```
private void setLocationManager() {
        if (lm == null)
            lm = (LocationManager) this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try {
            gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        try {
            network_enabled = lm
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        if (gps_enabled) {
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Refresh GPS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                    this);
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Refresh NET", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        MyCurrentLocation = location;
        Toast.makeText(
                HomeActivity.this,
                "Refresh == my lat : " + MyCurrentLocation.getLatitude()
                        + " my long : " + MyCurrentLocation.getLongitude(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, provider, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, provider, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

The problem I have are:

- The overriden method : onLocationChanged is never called using Network Provider
- The overriden method : onProviderDisabled is never called every time..

And I never use : lm.removeUpdate method

Comment: Have you considered the new functionality in Play Services. You can retrieve the current location from that. https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: The Network Provider not calling onLocationChanged is a known issue that surfaced when fused provider was released. Check https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57707 and https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55896. 

Funny thing is, that maps application (which probably uses the fused provider) get updates from Network Provider just fine. I would strongly suggest using the fused location provider for now.

Comment: +1 Bororo ! A rebboot did the tricks on my Samsung Galaxy S3, Android is boring..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reboot of my Samsung Galaxy S3 did the job..

Hope it helps.